# after onDestroy, the life cycle callbacks are re-called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

I have a main activity with viewpager and three tabs, each tab has its own fragment layout. in each of the three fragment i implemented the life cycle
call backs. The app was working fine till I pressed the the button that turns the screen off. when the screen turned off i found that after the
the three fragments destroyed they got recreated again and `onAttach`, `onCreate`,....etc were called again as well as shown in the logs posted below.

please let me know why when i turn the screen off `onAttach`, `onCreate`,.....etc are re-called?

**logcat**:

```
02-10 09:14:34.606 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_1: onPause()
02-10 09:14:34.606 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_2: onPause()
02-10 09:14:34.606 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_3: onPause()
02-10 09:14:34.606 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/MainActivity: onPause()
02-10 09:14:34.666 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_1: onStop()
02-10 09:14:34.666 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_2: onStop()
02-10 09:14:34.666 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_3: onStop()
02-10 09:14:34.666 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/MainActivity: onStop()
02-10 09:14:35.336 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_1: onDestroy()
02-10 09:14:35.336 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_2: onDestroy()
02-10 09:14:35.336 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_3: onDestroy()
02-10 09:14:35.336 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/MainActivity: onDestroy()
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_1: onAttach()
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_1: onCreate()
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_2: onAttach()
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/MainActivity: onFragRefHeld
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_2: onCreate()
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_3: onAttach()
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 V/Frag_3: getView(): null
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_3: onCreate()
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 V/Frag_3: getView(): null
02-10 09:14:35.456 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/MainActivity: onCreate()
02-10 09:14:35.466 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_1: onCreateView()
02-10 09:14:35.466 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_1: onViewCreated()
02-10 09:14:35.466 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_1: onActivityCreated()
02-10 09:14:35.466 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_2: onCreateView()
02-10 09:14:35.476 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 V/Frag_2: getView(): null
02-10 09:14:35.476 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_2: onViewCreated()
02-10 09:14:35.476 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_2: onActivityCreated()
02-10 09:14:35.476 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_3: onCreateView()
02-10 09:14:35.476 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 V/Frag_3: getView(): null
02-10 09:14:35.476 20109-20109/com.example.com.vpager_00 W/Frag_3: onViewCreated()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  When the screen turns off, Android may do whatever it wants with any activity the was visible in order to reclaim resources and help the device sleep while the screen is off.  You can always expect, if an app is not visible to the user, that Android may reclaim the resources that it takes.

You should always be prepared to handle lifecycle events and recover yourself when that happens.

Comment: but how recreating an activity or fragments helps in reclaiming resources?

Comment: When the system destroy objects, it uses less memory, right?

Comment: So when an Activity is no longer visible, Android may destroy its objects to reclaim memory.  And you have to be to able to deal with that when it happens.  This is the reason for the activity lifecycle - for you to respond to changing circumstances.

Comment: This is ridiculous, in my opinion.  My app is randomly killed for no good reason (it's not like the memory could be used for anything else, there is nothing else happening, and it's not like my app is using the CPU!), requiring me to use more resources to reinitialize as soon as the screen is turned on, also caused a noticable delay in the UI.